# Convert this upload image-application to MVC architecture

Tags: c#, c, image, model-view-controller

So I've created this image uploader following a tutorial. The problem is that i did all of it in the frame. Now i want to make it MVC. I've created classes for Controller and Dataaccesslayer. Can someone help me get started?

Regards William

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace ImageSaveToSQLServer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=localhost; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=ImageDataBase");
        SqlCommand command;
        string imgLoc = "";


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
                dlg.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
                dlg.Title = "Select Employee Picture"; 
                if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    imgLoc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
                    picEmp.ImageLocation = imgLoc;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {

                byte[] img = null;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgLoc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                string sql = "INSERT INTO Employee(EID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,IMAGE)VALUES("+textBoxEID.Text+",'"+textBoxFNAME.Text+"','"+textBoxLname.Text+"',@img)";
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img",img));
                int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();   

                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() + " record(s) saved.");
                textBoxEID.Text = "";
                textBoxFNAME.Text = "";
                textBoxLname.Text = "";
                picEmp.Image = null;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }

        private void buttonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string sql = "SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,IMAGE FROM Employee WHERE EID="+textBoxEID.Text+"";
                if(conn.State!=ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    textBoxFNAME.Text=reader[0].ToString();
                    textBoxLname.Text=reader[1].ToString();
                    byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[2]);
                    if(img==null)
                        picEmp.Image= null;

                    else
                    {

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                        picEmp.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("FINNS INTE");
                }
                conn.Close();

            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i leave you a link with a nice implementation, it has a demo so you wont have any kind of trouble testing it. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379980/Fancy-ASP-NET-MVC-Image-Uploader